# Is it possible to render flutter widgets while doing a widget test?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running a widget test and get an exception:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The
>   following assertion was thrown during layout: A RenderFlex overflowed
>   by 92 pixels on the bottom.

Running the code in the simulator seems to be ok. Is there a possibility to view the rendered widget on the desktop?

Comment: 1. Widget tests run with a different screen size (800x600), which is probably why you see different results. 2. You can do `flutter run test/YOUR_TEST_FILE.dart` to preview your widget test on a device or simulator.

Comment: Thans, that helped.